# Set operation of MySQL

Tags: mysql

can MySQL use Set operation `intersect`(∩) and `except`(-)? 
if can,please give a example 
if can't, then what's the operation instead?

Comment: unfortunately, mysql doesn't support both operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use intersect in mysql, but you have to write it a little differently. Here an example (and [here](http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71) a link to a nice description):

```
SELECT a.member_id, a.name
  FROM a INNER JOIN b
 USING (member_id, name)
```

You can find an example for except (minus) in the page also

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not support intersect and except, but you can achive this in other way.

Intersect:

```
SELECT a.x, a.y FROM a JOIN b ON a.x = b.x AND a.y = b.y;
```

Except:

```
SELECT a.* FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.x = a.x)
```

Comment: SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.x = a.x;  what's the 1 stand for?

Comment: @Froker The MySQL docs say: "Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference."