# Update a MySQL table from an HTML table with thousands of rows

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup, mysql-python

I have an html file on network which updates almost every minute with new rows in a table. At any point, the file contains close to 15000 rows I want to create a MySQL table with all data in the table, and then some more that I compute from the available data.

The said HTML table contains, say rows from the last 3 days. I want to store all of them in my mysql table, and update the table every hour or so (can this be done via a cron?)

For connecting to the DB, I'm using `MySQLdb` which works fine. However, I'm not sure what are the best practices to do so. I can scrape the data using `bs4`, connect to table using `MySQLdb`. But how should I update the table? What logic should I use to scrape the page that uses the least resources?

I am not fetching any results, just scraping and writing.

Any pointers, please?

Comment: Have you written any code yet? Example from your schema would be helpful as well!

Comment: All I have code for is, scraping the HTML table rows, and writing them to table one at a time. However, what I really worry about is updating the table and performance issues.

Comment: Make a scraper that outputs CSV.  Then load the CSV into mysql using LOAD DATA INFILE or similar.  Also, if you need to further filter or monitor things before committing to use the data , then using a separate table for uploading, and then doing an INSERT/SELECT to copy over, might be advisable.

Comment: I'd just do an ad hoc implementation first, benchmark it, and rewrite to optimize if necessary. Don't worry before you have something to worry about!

Comment: @Paul I do not have to write to any file. Everything must run on it's own without requiring any other layers.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is instead of updating values row by row try to use Bulk Insert in temporary table and then move the data into an actual table based on some timing key. If you have key column that will be good for reading the recent rows as you added.

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt the following approach:

For the purpose of the discussion, let **master** be the final destination the scraped data.
Then we can adopt the following steps:

1. Scrape data from the web page.
2. Store this scraped data within the temporary table within MySQL say **temp**.
3. Perform an EXCEPT operation to pull out only those rows which exist within the **master** but not in **temp**.
4. persist the rows obtained in step 3 within the **master** table.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834623/set-operation-of-mysql) link for understanding how to perform SET operations in MySQL. Also, it would be advisable to place all this logic within a store procedure and pass it the set of the data to be processed ( not sure if this part is possible in MySQL)
 **Adding one more step to the approach** - Based on the discussion below, we can use a timestamp based column to determine the newest rows that need to be placed into the table. The above approach for SET based operations works well, in case there are no timestamp based columns.

Comment: The problem with this is that while the HTML table will have last 3 days' records, the database will have records since the beginning of it's time.

Comment: @KaranGoel I have updated my answer - in case you have a time based column you can compare based on time to determine whether the records need to be inserted into the database. The SET based approach works well when you do not have timestamp based attributes with the data.